# Rendering issues with our Docusaurus wiki

Tags: rendering, docusaurus

Rendering issues with our Docusaurus wiki page, when I navigate from staring the right pane renders properly beside left navigation pane, however when I refresh the page after navigating, the right pane loads at the bottom instead on the side to left navigation page

Right page to render properly beside left navigation pane even when refreshed.